# Couldn't determine VC14 directory

Tags: windows, visual-studio, php-7.2

Trying to build php 7.2 on windows 
`c:\php-sdk\phpsdk-vc15-x64.bat`

`Couldn't determine VC14 directory`
Is there anything to install that is missing!!

Comment: It appears as though you are planning to compile using Visual Studio 2015. Do you have Visual Studio 2015 installed?

Comment: I do, and it fails to recognize it, 2015 and 2017

Comment: Presumably you'll need to launch the build script from a Developer Command Prompt, that gets installed with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installed visual studio express from another source, and it worked